# Click event bubbling issue

Tags: javascript, click

I have a div that has it's own click event.  Inside that div, I also have a link.

My issue is, clicking on the div, expands and collapse it. However, I don't want it to expand or collapse if the link is clicked. How do I achieve this?

```
<div class="module">
    BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA <a href="http://www.google.com">Googs</a>
</div>
```

Comment: And what does the function that expands and collapses look like ?

Comment: can we have your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the stopPropagation() on the link to avoid going up the chain

inline

```
<div class="module">
    BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onClick="event.stopPropagation();">Googs</a>
</div>
```

jquery
**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/udkDa/)**

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: he doesn't said he is using jQuery

Comment: Maybe because it's **[more standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)**.

Answer (score 0):

event.stopPropagation() will prevent the event from being passed up to the parent's handler. E.g.:

```
$('.module > a').on('click', function(e) {
    // do stuff, or not
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```